# How to query a file system using MS SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have a CMS system that stores user information in a SQL database, but the user profile images are in a file system on the Windows server that SQL runs on.  Each user has a corresponding folder based on their userid.

Given a userid, how can I query the file system for the corresponding profile picture name?  Ultimately, I would like to create a table that stores userid and profile picture name... Have this query run periodically.

Thanks.

Comment: Make a windows service instead... I.e. query database from the application and not folder from database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349552/using-t-sql-to-query-a-file-system-folder but i am not sure if you can query this result or not

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a file table.  Here is a pretty good blog on the topic.
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/14/sql-server-working-with-filetables-in-sql-server-2012-part-1-setting-up-environment/

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to enable xp_cmpshell because of security.

If you are working on a web application, try fetch picture names using the web app, not database.

You also can use FileStreem feature of SQL Server. It does the same thing more convenient and secure. This way your pictures will be part of database so you can use TRANSACTION and include them in backup/restore operation.

[FileStream](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/)