# Access files on another PC on the same network with SQL accounts that has access to the database only

Tags: sql, sql-server, winforms

I'm making a windows form application using C# for a local database, paths of files like images and videos are stored in this database, so I was wondering is there a way to open these files on a different PC with only accounts that has access to the database? I thought of putting the files on windows network but that wouldn't be secure because everyone on the network would have access to them not only who has access to the database.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using T-SQL to Query a File System Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349552/using-t-sql-to-query-a-file-system-folder)

Comment: No i want to open the file on a different pc not get its info

Comment: "I thought of putting the files on windows network but that wouldn't be secure because everyone on the network would have access to them" make a network directory that only some users are allowed to access, put the files in there, profit.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can set security for shared folder with a specific account that run application (recommended specific windows/domain user or group that access database and also shared folder).(on offer [lan Kemp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70345/ian-kemp) answer)

2) You can access to shared folder via Network Drive and using below script to map before access to shared folder :

```
EXECUTE SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
EXECUTE SP_CONFIGURE 'xp_cmdshell', '1'
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
EXECUTE SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 0
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE


EXEC xp_cmdshell 'net use   z:   \\PC or IP\share   password  /user:domain\user /y '
```

and disconnect after access to shared folder :

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'net use z: /delete /y'

EXECUTE SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
EXECUTE SP_CONFIGURE 'xp_cmdshell', '0'
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
EXECUTE SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 0
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
```